# htaccess mod_rewrite RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to set up an .htaccess file to convert an incoming link like:

http://domain.com/root/TopNav/SubNav/SEO-friendly-file-name-p#

into this:

http://domain.com/root/index.php?t=TopNav&s=SubNav&l=SEO-friendly-file-name&p=#

where p# is the page id and TopNav/SubNav represent the navigation menu path to the file

I have been able to get it to work in all cases except for when there are arguments after the .php (it does the mod rewrite, but loses the parameters).  Originally, I was hoping to have the .htaccess parse the url string so that it was ready for the script to use, but at this point I would be happy with any solution that takes the incoming url and dumps it as a string onto root/index.php.

here's what I currently have in the .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.php     index.php?s=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/          index.php?p=$1&s=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?  Suggestions of a better way to get this done?

Thanks

** someone suggested changing the [L] to [L,QSA] and that seems to have worked.  Thanks, whoever suggested that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a URU that looks like this: `/TopNav/SubNav/SEO-friendly-file-name-p#` you've got 4 groupings you need:

1. TopNav
2. SubNav
3. SEO-friendly-file-name
4. #

So you need to craft your regex so that it captures these 4 things in one go.

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+?)-p([0-9]+)$ index.php?t=$1&s=$2&l=$3&p=$4 [L,QSA]
```

This would go in the htaccess file in your `/root` directory